# How to tell if someone is using Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I am browsing suggested people and adding them to my circles, but how do I know whether they are using Google+?

I don't want to add someone who is not a Google+ user or at least, I would like to know that so I can invite them.

Comment: @Zile: If you create an account here and associate it with your Super User account, you'll regain control of this question.

Answer (score 14):

When you add him in your list, if you only see the mail icon this mean your contact don't have Google+.

By the way if you click on the icon of a contact without an account, it will invite you to share by email or send (eventually) an invite.

Comment: I guess, to be more precise: *that email address of your contact is not linked with a google+ account*. The Contace *may* have a google+ account but *may* have created it with a different email address/google profile.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [what M'vy said](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17134/how-to-tell-if-someone-is-using-google/17135#17135)...

When you're looking at your Circles page at the "Find and invite" section, the list of suggested people is broken down into two lists:

- Suggestions - people who you may know on Google+
- People not yet using Google+ - you can still share with them via email

Answer (score 0):

On the "suggestions" list on the main page (unlike everywhere else on google+) there is no envelope to denote which people are not on google+.  Instead you can tell the difference by scrolling over the person's name and seeing if it is a link to their profile.

Warning: the text of their name will be blue whether or not it is a link!